# Creating a solr collection with curl

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am trying to create collection in solr cloud,

```
https://abc.a/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=123&configSet=super&numShards=2&replicationFactor=2&maxShardsPerNode=2&wt=json
```

The collection is created, but the `configSet` is created using `_default`
besides the specified configSet  `"super"`

`super` configuration already uploaded to zookeeper.

Comment: Do you need to use `collection.configName=super` instead? What version of Solr are you running?

Comment: yes exactly .. version 8.4.1

Comment: So does it work now?

Comment: collection created using the default one not the specified one "super"

Comment: According [to the documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/collection-management.html#collection-management) the parameter is named `collection.configName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below url to create the collection

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=TestDemo4&numShards=1&replicationFactor=1&createNodeSet=localhost:8983_solr&collection.configName=pkiConfig
```

The response you get is :

```
{
  "responseHeader":
   {
    "status":0,
    "QTime":697 
   }
}
```

In the solr admin page you check the collection and verify which configset is been used for the collection.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61346386/solr-cloud-log-explination-for-solr-velocityresponsewriter