# SolrCloud error loading solr.VelocityResponseWriter

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

I am getting this error in the logs. I did not configure any `solr.VelocityResponseWriter` in solrConfig.

```
ERROR:[{
"update-queryresponsewriter":{
  "startup":"lazy",
  "name":"velocity",
  "class":"solr.VelocityResponseWriter",
  "template.base.dir":"",
  "solr.resource.loader.enabled":"true",
  "params.resource.loader.enabled":"true"},
"errorMessages":["Error loading class 'solr.VelocityResponseWriter'"]}]
```

I am using **Solr version 8.4** as SolrCloud [image]

Comment: When are you getting this error? what operation/action you are performing?

Comment: When i saw logging from admin panel I found this error.After i tried to add and search but not able to replicate the log

Comment: copy the "solr-velocity-7.5.0" jar from "...\solr-7.5.0\dist" to "...\solr-7.5.0\server\solr-webapp\webapp\WEB-INF\lib...